# Android ant build "nocompression" tag

Tags: android, ant

In sdk/tools/ant/build.xml

```
<!-- <nocompress /> forces no compression on any files in assets or res/raw -->
```

When i turned off compression, i has following error:

> ANTBUILD : [aapt] error : '..\AndroidApk\AndroidManifest.xml' is not a directory

Android SDK Tools rev 14, 
Android SDK Platform-tools rev 8

Comment: Can you post the entire <aapt> section from your build.xml where you disabled compression?

Comment: http://www.everfall.com/paste/id.php?douzcu7mz6i7

Comment: Just hit this myself, there is a bug logged here: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=23894